# MeshRefinementFunction for region gives error

Tags: functions, finite-element-method, mesh

I would like to refine a mesh within a given path/volume, that is specified by the MeshRefinementFunction option given in ToElementMesh[].
For starting i took a simple 3D MeshRegion of a Tetrahedron

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
reg=MeshRegion[{{0,0,0},{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}},Tetrahedron[{1,2,3,4}]]
```

[image]

Next i defined the MeshRefinementFunction

```
coord={{0,0,0},{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}};
cf = Function[{coordinates, vol},RegionMember[Ball[Mean[coord], 0.5], Mean[coordinates]]];
```

So that whenever the element lies within the balls region there should be a refinement. Then i proceed with

`mesh = ToElementMesh[reg,MeshRefinementFunction -> cf]`

which evaluates to the error code

> ToElementMesh::mrff: The MeshRefinementFunction Function[{coordinates,vol},RegionMember[Ball[Mean[coord],0.5],Mean[coordinates]]] is not valid and will be ignored. Possibly the function does not return either True or False or the (auto) compiled function does not evaluate message free.

I dont understand whats the problem in here. cf evaluates to True or False as required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that the error message is a bit confusing. <s>Maybe the problem is that this `MeshRefinementFunction` is not compilable?</s> It seems that `coordinates` not being inlined correctly into the pure function leads to problems: The autocompilation might be run with options `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True`. Since `coordinates` is not inlined, there may occur calls to `MainEvaluate` which will lead to a warning message that this cannot be run in parallel. And this warning message will cause that

> the (auto) compiled function does not evaluate message free.

The following seems to work, although `RegionMemberFunction`s in general are not compilable to my knowledge (but for very simple regions like `Ball` and `Cuboid`, they are).

Notice that your original `MeshRefinementFunction` would lead to an infinite recursion of refinements which is why I added an upper bound for the elements' volume.

```
coord = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
cf = With[{f = RegionMember[Ball[Mean[coord], 0.5]]}, 
 Function[{coordinates, vol}, vol > 0.00001 && f[Mean[coordinates]]]
 ];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, MeshRefinementFunction -> cf]
```

By the way: This uses the operator version of `RegionMember` which might be more efficient than calling `RegionMember[Ball[Mean[coord], 0.5], Mean[coordinates]]` multiple times.

You can even save about one third of runtime (with essentially the same result) by using this more elementary `MeshRefinementFunction`

```
cf = Function[{coordinates, vol}, vol > 0.00001 && Norm[Mean[N@coord] - Mean[coordinates]] <= 0.5]
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, how should the message be written such that it is not confusing? If you have a suggestion I could improve the text.

Comment: @user21 Hmm. Good question. Speaking for myself, I stopped reading after "True or False". Several times. =/ Then I moved directly to the doc page of `MeshRefinementFunction`. And the only criterion for validity that is stated there is that the function returns a Boolean. After several rounds of guessing and trying, I finally saw "(auto) compiled function". Finally, that drove me to the conclusion that I posted above. 

I thought a lot about this but did not find a satisfactory answer. Maybe the problem is too complex for a single error message. I see the following issues:

Comment: (i) The error message tries to cope with two rather different problems: The first problem is that the `MeshRefinementFunction` might be invalid in the sense that it does not evaluate to a Boolean. Imho, this will be the most frequently occuring problem so that it quite likely focusses all the users attention to it.
The second is basically about the function not being compilable or not parallelizing correctly. 
Sure, it would be a bit tedious, but maybe the error handling can be made a bit more fine-grained? (Two different error messages instead of one.)

Comment: (ii) The generic user cannot grasp the meaning of the part the message that involves compiled functions. One needs a bit of experience with `Compile` in order to understand it. Moreover, the compilation happens in the background so that the user has no idea what is going on. And even the more experienced user cannot inspect the compiled function in order to single out the problem. 
Maybe the user can be spared from all these things by manipulating the backend code a bit?

Comment: Can TetGenLink handle uncompiled refinement functions (e.g. by means of some reverse communication interface like Intel's FGMRES routines)? Then a noncompilable refinement function would not be an issue at all. But I expect that it requires a pointer to a library function instead.

Comment: (iii) The doc page of `MeshRefinementFunction` does not state the requirement that the function should be compilable. Actually, `DiscretizeRegion[reg, MeshRefinementFunction -> cf]` just ignores `cf = Function[{coordinates, vol}, vol > 0.00001 && RegionMember[Ball[Mean[coord], 0.5], Mean[coordinates]]];` without any message; that is also not a good user experience. If TetGenLink really cannot handle uncompiled refinement functions, in might be worth adding a section "Possible issues" that explains that.

Comment: (iv) The user cannot get more information on how to mend the issue, neither from the message nor from the doc page. I like error and warning messages that tell me to try this or that. For example, you could encourage the use to provide a `CompiledFunction` as `MeshRefinementFunction` and to check that the result of ``CompiledFuntionTools`CompilePrint`` is free of `MainEvaluate`?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, thanks for the detailed response. How about the message text: "The MeshRefinementFunction XXX is not valid and will be ignored. Possibly the function does not return either True or False or the (auto) compilation failed. Try to provide a compiled function that evaluates to True or False with the arguments of YYYY" where YYYY in this case would be `{{0., 0., 0.}, {1., 0., 0.}, {0., 1., 0.}, {0., 0., 1.}}, 1/6.} `.

Comment: Yeah, that could be a step forward. Yet, as a user, I would be prefer to be told which one of the to possible issues is the one that I should tackle.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, OK, I'll see what can be done.

Comment: @user21 That would be great. I really appreciate that you take interaction with users so seriously!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, as a side note, the CF does not have to be free of `MainEvaluate` in fact that is the mechanism for a general call back from Triangle/TetGen for arbitrary functions. The problem in this case is that the compilation does not happen message free. One would have to go through some length to see if the CF is still OK to use, so I just gave a message (which I think is better then not saying anything at all).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, I try my best to write a half decent FEM environment.

Comment: @user21 I'd say the first half is already great! Now it is about the other half ;)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, stay tuned for that other half ;-)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, you are not by any chance going to be in the US for the WTC conference, or are you?

Comment: @user21 Nope, sorry.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, just a quick ping: I just merged the new code: So will get a different message when the function does not return True|False or a different one when the compilation does not work and it suggests with which arguments the compiled function needs to work.